# How to rotate an image a random degree in PHP?

Tags: php, html, rotation

I am new to coding, so I apologize if this is a silly question. I've tried searching for answers, but can't figure it out. I am trying to make an image move to a random position and rotate a random number of degrees on a page. I have the position working, but the rotation does not work:

```
    <?php
     $Racism_image= 'img1.png';
     $Racism_top= rand(0, 700);
     $Racism_left= rand(0,1500);
     $Racism_rot= rand(0,360);
    ?>
    <div class= 'racism'>
     <img src= "<?php echo $Racism_image?>" 
     style="width:<?php echo $Racism_width;?>px; 
     padding-top:<?php echo $Racism_top;?>px;
     padding-left:<?php echo $Racism_left;?>px;"
     transform= "rotate (<?php echo $Racism_rot;?>deg);"
     />
    </div>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Comment: follow http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did find this resource when I was researching, but I don't really understand how to implement it. Where should it go relative to what I have? And will it work if I am also placing the image in a random position?

Comment: From your code above, you put `transform` outside `style` attribute. `transform` is a css property, not an `img` tag attribute; it should be inside `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

use php [rand()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_rand.asp)

```
transform= "rotate (<?php echo rand(min,max); ?> deg);"// or simply rand()
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You got several extra `"` quotes in your code and an `=` after `transform`, when it should be a colon `:`.  Try this

```
<div class= 'racism'>
 <img src= "<?php echo $Racism_image?>" 
 style="width:<?php echo $Racism_width;?>px; 
 padding-top:<?php echo $Racism_top;?>px;
 padding-left:<?php echo $Racism_left;?>px;
 transform: rotate (<?php echo $Racism_rot;?>deg);"
 />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out after all. I had to make a class "rotate" and apply that to the image, then I did:

```
     <style>
       .rotate{
       transform: rotate(<?php echo rand(0,360);?>deg);
       }
     </style>
```

This worked out for me. Thanks for all of the help everyone!